# Multi-language application: store/read translation

Tags: php, mysql, file

I need to make a multi-language application using php and have to choose between store the phrases into database(MYSQL - innodb) or use files (xml/text/ etc...).

The problem is that every phrase must be read in every page request and I don't really know how much processing this will cost

Which one should I use?

- If you know any already made solution it will be very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep these phrases in you php file(not in some other file on disk) or you can use MYSQL database.

First option is better than the other